# Monument.ai only shows bar chart, not line chart

Tags: graph

I downloaded [monument.ai](https://www.monument.ai/) a while ago and was trying it out with my data. It shows only the bar chart instead of line chart. Does anyone else have this problem? How can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have actually resolved this problem by reconstructing my date format. If Monument.ai doesnt recognize the data format, it will not treat it as a time series, thus no line chart.